# Inner Div is Spilling from outer div due to fixed aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

The page in question is: http://956.da2.myftpupload.com/home-new/

As you can see in some resolutions (1000px to 1400px wide) the innerdiv is spilling from the container div. I have set the outer div to a fixed aspect ratio and I believe this is the cause. There are resolutions that they look fine but I would like to make it look consistent all throughout.

Here's my code for both outer and inner divs:

```
.boxcontainer {
    padding-top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.innerbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(http://956.da2.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/G2-Down-Arrow-1-50x50.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: 90%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What do I need to add to my code? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just put `bottom: 0px;` on innerbox?

Comment: I did tried that. It's not working.

Comment: I tried it on your example, and that made the innerbox fill boxcontainer. Is that not the effect you want?

Comment: yes it fills but my concern is it overflows on certain resolutions. https://www.screencast.com/t/zyPhfMcHLH

Comment: Why are you using multiple grids? Both bootstrap and something that absolute positions items? That is probably why you have the overflow problem. A lot of absolute positioned stuff.

Comment: try removing height: 100% from .innerbox styling

Comment: @andeersg because I want the background image to be at a fixed scale of 2:1. I am using Visual Composer

Comment: If you want your image to fill the wrapper no matter what, try `background-size: cover;`. But you should consider learning html/css, visual editors do a lot of strange stuff.